# Getting HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found error when loaded a dataset using seaborn

Tags: seaborn

I have a dataset with name "haberman.csv" in my current directory and upon trying to load the dataset with below load_dataset function then it throws an error saying `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`.

But when loaded a different dataset with name "tips.csv" in the same directory it works well.

What is the reason behind this error that one dataset when loaded works and another doesn't.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
haberman_plot = sns.load_dataset("haberman")
```

## Error:

````
<ipython-input-58-fb9fa2439b0a> in <module>()
      4 
      5 sns.set()
----> 6 haberman_plot = sns.load_dataset("haberman")

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py in load_dataset(name, cache, data_home, **kws)
    426                                   os.path.basename(full_path))
    427         if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
--> 428             urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)
    429         full_path = cache_path
    430 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    246     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    247 
--> 248     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    249         headers = fp.info()
    250 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568         if http_err:
    569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
    571 
    572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found```
````